# Por que criar uma interface para cada DAO?

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, interface

Vejo muito na internet a criação de uma interface para cada DAO do sistema. Eu entendo a importância de se usar interface principalmente para uma troca fácil de implementação, já encontrei inclusive uma explicação dizendo se você usa um banco de dados e troca pra outro é só criar DAO's novos e avisar pra injeção de dependência quais são os novos que ela deve injetar... enfim, em tempos de ORM não vejo a necessidade de se trocar o DAO inteiro, dependendo como foi programado apenas uns ajustes na troca de BD.

Então se tenho um sistema com duas tabelas apenas **Usuario** e **Pedido** (por exemplo), qual seria a vantagem de eu criar as interfaces UsuarioDAO e PedidoDAO para depois criar as implementações delas UsarioDaoImlp e PedidoDaoImpl?

Comment: Se você não percebe a necessidade de uma interface, é porque você não deve criá-la. Crie apenas as interfaces que você notou que já são necessárias agora mesmo. Criar interface para o caso de um dia precisar substituir a implementação é um motivo ruim para criá-la. Só devemos escrever agora o código que é necessário agora, evitando desperdício e aumento desnecessário da complexidade.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isso depende mais da “tecnologia ao redor” e dos planos para o futuro, e não é necessariamente uma regra geral.

Por exemplo, o que eu quero dizer com “tecnologia ao redor”? Se você está falando de Java, era comum certas tecnologias mais antigas como o J2EE até o 1.4 (renomeado para JavaEE a partir da versão 5 e muito simplificado) exigirem a criação de várias interfaces e factories. Ou se não obrigava, a quantidade de boilerplate era tanta que o programador acabava separando as partes de qualquer jeito para reaproveitar código e separar responsabilidades.

Existe um livro justamente sobre “repensar” certas práticas que podem ter ficado obsoletas com o tempo em novas versões dos frameworks Java:

[http://www.amazon.com/Real-World-Patterns-Rethinking-Practices/dp/0557078326](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0557078326)

Um dos motivos para a criação de interfaces é para possibilitar chamadas remotas de métodos, algo muito mais enfatizado no início do JavaEE. Se chamadas remotas estiverem nos planos, uma interface separada para os clientes chamarem será útil em vez de amarrá-los diretamente a uma classe com implementação que deverá estar no mesmo projeto.

Outro motivo para a interface é para separar e abstrair a instanciação do DAO. Usando uma Factory, o DAO pode ser qualquer coisa: uma classe normal, um proxy para uma chamada remota, um pool de objetos reaproveitados, etc. sendo acessado apenas pela interface, sem tocar no objeto real. Esse padrão de design em JavaEE é menos necessário na presença do CDI: com @Inject você fica livre para decidir depois como será a instanciação da sua classe, sem precisar escrever factories, e também sem precisar criar uma interface separada.

Obs.: não tenho experiência com a injeção do Spring para comparar com CDI, mas bem... nem tenho certeza se a pergunta é sobre Java mesmo ou se é independente de linguagem.

E um terceiro motivo para ter uma interface aquele que você falou na sua pergunta: separação normal entre interface e implementação.

Agora, se alguma dessas situações se aplica ao seu caso, aí tem que pensar com cuidado (nenhuma regrinha fácil substitui o pensar!). Em geral eu prefiro seguir o [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it%20YAGNI), e não codificar nada cuja utilidade não seja <strike>previsível</strike> visível. É importante separar os módulos da sua aplicação, mas raramente precisa fazer picadinho transformando cada classe em 3 (interface, implementação e factory).

Muitas vezes as necessidades futuras são tão diferentes do previsto que vale a pena ter algo mais simples. O que acontece com mais freqüência? Trocar todo o banco de dados ou adicionar uma coluna nova ou regra de validação? Codifique para deixar fácil o que acontece com mais freqüência.

Comment: No capítulo 6 do livro que linkei tem uma seção chamada “Premature encapsulation is the root of all evil”, hahahahaha.

Comment: YAGNI é um pouco mais rigoroso que isso. Em vez de dizer para "não codificar nada cuja utilidade não seja previsível", ele diz "não codifique nada que você não esteja precisando agora mesmo".

Comment: Hehe, eu devia ter dito “visível” em vez de “previsível” então ;-)

Comment: Marcus só pra citar, no meu caso é java e pretendo usar as especificações do EE, mas a ideia era sim ser algo independente de linguagem. Mas com sua resposta percebi que a linguagem realmente importa nestes casos pois recursos como DI podem fazer a diferença na escolha dos padrões e modo de programar.
@Caffé obrigado pelas contribuições que desde o inicio de forma resumida deu uma resposta similar á do Marcus!

Comment: Outra coisa que lembrei agora que muda muito a abordagem da programação é quem vai usar seu código: você está fazendo uma lib/serviço para outras pessoas (melhor ter um bom encapsulamento desde cedo) ou um programa só para você mesmo (se não ficou bom, é só ir lá no código e refatorar tudo, pronto!)

Comment: Só para esclarecimento, até recentemente o framework Spring exigia a criação de interfaces para possibilitar a criação de proxies em casos particulares. Por exemplo, se você injeta um bean de escopo de sessão, o Spring na verdade injeta um proxy que em tempo de execução irá delegar as chamadas aos métodos do *bean* para a instância da sessão do usuário. O problema é que a implementação do Spring (que usa Javassist) para geração de proxies dinâmicos não consegue gerar o proxy se houver um construtor que não seja o *default*.

Answer (score 6):

A principal vantagem está na evolução e na modularização do sistema.

Temos duas possíveis abordagens:

1. Criar 20 interfaces `DAO` com 5 ou 6 métodos cada, você tem interfaces `UsuarioDAO`, `PedidoDAO`, `ContaDAO`, `ClienteDAO`... Quando você for criar o módulo de vendedores, você vai criar um `VendedorDAO`, alguns poucos métodos e um `VendedorDAOImpl`.
2. Criar uma única gigantesca interface `MegaDAO` com uns 100 métodos lá. Quando você for criar o módulo de vendedores, você vai acrescentar mais alguns métodos lá e implementá-los no `MegaDAOImpl`.

Agora vamos analisar as vantagens e desvantagens de cada alternativa:

Observe que na abordagem 2, o seu `MegaDAO` não é uma interface estável no tempo, pois ela está sempre mudando. As implementações desta interface (`MegaDAOImpl`) também não são estáveis no tempo, pois estão sempre mudando. Sempre que você cria ou altera algum módulo de forma que o acesso ao banco de dados mude, o `MegaDAO` e o `MegaDAOImpl` vão sofrer alterações.

A abordagem 2 também dificulta a modularização, pois ela cria uma interface da qual todos os módulos do sistema dependem, e efetivamente ela amarra todas as partes do sistema umas com as outras em um único bloco monolítico, mesmo que as diferentes partes tenham pouca ou nenhuma relação entre si. Se você quiser depois separar o programa em dois, um para o setor de contabilidade e o outro para o setor de manutenção, o seu `MegaDAO` e todas as suas implementações (mesmo que seja uma só) vai te dar dor-de-cabeça, pois ele coloca todas as funcionalidades do sistema juntas, inclusive aquelas que forem dispensáveis para o cenário em questão. O resultado disso é o famoso *software bloat*.

Além disso, vamos supor que o módulo de consulta de nota fiscal tem uma peculiaridade: Ele utiliza dois bancos de dados distintos por qualquer razão especial. Na abordagem 1, este é um detalhe do `ConsultaNotaFiscalDAO` e de suas (possivelmente múltiplas) implementações. Se você tiver um único `MegaDAO`, vai precisar resolver isso com uma gambiarra ou com um refactoring completo, pois haverá uma grande quantidade de métodos aonde o uso de dois bancos de dados não faz nenhum sentido, e com isso há o risco (pode ser ou pode não ser que aconteça) de a gambiarra (ou a necessidade de refactoring completo) acabar cascateando uma série de mudanças em outras partes do sistema que não deveriam estar sofrendo alteração.

Normalmente a implementação da maioria dos `DAO`s será bem parecida: Ele vai no ORM e consulta, insere, altera e/ou exclui registros. No entanto "normalmente" e "a maioria" não é a mesma coisa do que "sempre" e "todos". Se houver uma exceção, digamos, o `PrazoDeEntregaDAO` que ao invés de ir no banco de dados relacional, vai em um serviço externo, ele trará problemas na abordagem 2 e vai complicar o seu `MegaDAOImpl`.

Talvez você argumente que neste caso o `PrazoDeEntregaDAO` nem sequer deveria ser um `DAO`. Mas vamos supor que originalmente ele era um `DAO` e com o tempo ele evoluiu para este comportamento especial. Na abordagem 1, tudo que você vai precisar fazer vai ser trocar a implementação do `DAO` por uma implementação especial diferente do normal. Na abordagem 2, você vai estar ferrado.

Vamos supor que você esteja rascunhando como será a implementação do `ChatDAO`. Para isso você criou um mock rápido que salva as informações apenas na memória, o `ChatDAOMockImpl`. Você também usa esta implementação para fazer testes de unidade. Isso é simples e natural na abordagem 1. Já na abordagem 2, você se ferra de novo.

Na abordagem 2, a medida que o seu sistema cresce, o `MegaDAO` e o `MegaDAOImpl` também crescem. Imagine que depois de 5 anos, você acrescentou mais de 40 módulos distintos e tem um sistema de grande porte com vários desenvolvedores trabalhando. E também tem um `MegaDAOImpl` com umas vinte mil linhas de código que a sua IDE até tem dificuldade para abrir e os desenvolvedores constantemente reclamando de problemas de merge com o git ou svn nesta classe.

Enfim, o problema do seu `DAO` único é que você viola vários princípios de programação orientada a objetos:

- A implementação do seu `DAO` único será uma [*god class*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object), que consiste em um dos piores anti-padrões de programação orientada a objetos.
- O seu sistema terá um [alto grau de acoplamento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loose_coupling), pois o seu `DAO` (tanto a interface quanto a implementação) amarram tudo a tudo.
- O seu sistema terá um [baixo grau de coesão](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_(computer_science)), pois uma grande quantidade de funcionalidades não relacionadas entre si ou pouco relacionadas entre si estarão coexistindo na mesma classe.
- Você estará violando o [princípio do aberto-fechado](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), aonde as funcionalidades devem ser estensíveis e reutilizáveis sem a necessidade de modificação de código já existente. Com um `DAO` único, qualquer tentativa de aumentar as funcionalidades implicam em uma alteração de código.
- Você estará violando o [princípio da responsabilidade única](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), pois a sua interface `DAO` (bem como a implementação) terá um monte de responsabilidades distintas, e como resultado, será difícil de ser utilizada.
- Você estará violando, de forma bem direta, o [princípio de segregação de interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle), que diz que várias interfaces de propósito específico são melhores do que uma única grande interface de propósito genérico.

A única vantagem da abordagem 2 é ter o código todo em um só lugar e simplificar um pouco os métodos de gerenciamento de conexão com o banco de dados, consultas genéricas e coisas assim. E é só isso. Esta vantagem é facilmente derrotada pela grande quantidade de desvantagens.

Você talvez possa argumentar, ah mas eu só tenho dois módulos, *Usuario* e *Pedido*, preciso mesmo separar? A resposta é que todo o sistema que se torna grande começa pequeno, então quanto antes eles forem separados, mais fácil vai ser a evolução do sistema.

Comment: No meu entendimento, a pergunta se referia ao motivo de separar a interface DAO da implementação DAOImpl, e não ao motivo de separar Usuario de Pedido.

Comment: Victor, sua resposta foi muito completa da até gosto de ler! Falou de conceitos que eu já possuía mas foi muito além do que eu sabia, aprendi mais um pouco com esta sua resposta! Mas não é minha ideia fazer um **super dao** já fiz muito isso e sei a dor de cabeça que isso gera. Eu prefiro usar para estes casos composição ao invés de herança. Mas como o @marcus quis dizer, minha dúvida estava na real necessidade de ficar fazendo interfaces para todos os DAOs, e talvez faltou eu citar justamente isso, que meus DAOs não são extensões de um genericDAO.

Comment: @FlavioAndrade Beleza, tudo bem.